# Mapped network drive not working, yet the same network location is flawless

Tags: networking, network-drive, network-location

I'm working a client's PC, but for some reason I'm having trouble with a certain file type opening properly, but it's stumped me. There is a mapped network drive :

```
\\company\users\username
```

That when the files are accessed from tells me they don't exist. However, if I open up explorer and manually go to the same address and try opening the same file it works flawlessly. Anyone have any suggestions? I'm, quite stumped now.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Which errors (multiple?) do you get? Also `\company\users\username` or `\\company\users\username` ? Uhm, never mind part 2, in edit mode I see two backslashes. As posted only one shows up. Will edit.

Comment: Claims the file doesn't exist. It's also \\company\users\username

No idea why it got rid of the first \ 

Editing now.

Comment: Any spaces in the username or anywhere in the path?

Comment: No sir. Spaces are represented with hyphens in this naming scheme.

Comment: Have you tried removing the map and recreating it?

Comment: Yes I have. I guess I'm really just trying to get help on whether or not its a issue with the mapping or an issue with the software being used to open said files.